# Sauvola local image thresholding

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold, image-thresholding, adaptive-threshold

How to apply Sauvola local image thresholding by MATLAB? I downloded the File Exchange contribution:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40266-sauvola-local-image-thresholding?tab=reviews%2F2147193

But I don’t know how to use it?
Can anyone excplain how to use Sauvola and write the code use for it to find threshold the code available in MATLAB as following

```
function output=sauvola(image, varargin)
% Initialization
numvarargs = length(varargin);      % only want 3 optional inputs at most
if numvarargs > 3
    error('myfuns:somefun2Alt:TooManyInputs', ...
    'Possible parameters are: (image, [m n], threshold, padding)');
end

optargs = {[3 3] 0.34 'replicate'}; % set defaults

optargs(1:numvarargs) = varargin;   % use memorable variable names
[window, k, padding] = optargs{:};

if ndims(image) ~= 2
    error('The input image must be a two-dimensional array.');
end

% Convert to double
image = double(image);

% Mean value
mean = averagefilter(image, window, padding);

% Standard deviation
meanSquare = averagefilter(image.^2, window, padding);
deviation = (meanSquare - mean.^2).^0.5;

% Sauvola
R = max(deviation(:));
threshold = mean.*(1 + k * (deviation / R-1));
output = (image > threshold);
end
 I=imread('blir.jpg');
 % Mean value
 mean = averagefilter(image, window, padding);

% Standard deviation
meanSquare = averagefilter(image.^2, window, padding);
deviation = (meanSquare - mean.^2).^0.5;

% Sauvola
R = max(deviation(:));
threshold = mean.*(1 + k * (deviation / R-1));
output = (image > threshold);
```

How to use them?

```
output=sauvola(I, varargin)
```

Comment: “Can someone write code for me” is kind of a rude thing to ask. It seems this function just needs an image as input. Did you try that?

Comment: I didnt mean to write code, Exchange file of Sauvola is already in matlab and I attached it if you read my question carefully, but the problem is appearing of error when I enter the image